# Некорректно работает ввод номера карты с плагином маски ввода данных в input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не корректно работает ввод номера карты с плагином маски ввода данных в input. При вводе номера карты числа заменяются...

Маска для поля ввода номера карты:

```
$("#cardNumber").mask("9999 9999 9999 9999?999");
```

Вроде бы ошибка в том, что плагин не учитывает длину, т.е. при достижении максимума не блочит ввод, а продолжение ввода сдвигает предыдущее..

Как это можно исправить?

[Полный код](http://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/vkfarha6/)

P.S. в примере jsfiddle подключила плагины, но почему-то не срабатывают)

**UPD** ошибка в следующем.

Введен номер карты, например такой `9000 6757 9090 9090900`.
При попытке отредактировать эту часть номера 6757, например, заменить на число 8.

Если случайно нажму два раза число 8, то все число 6757, заменится на 8857.

В итоге номер карты станет такой `9000 8857 9090 9090900`.

**UPD 1.1** обнаружила еще баги. поиск не дал результатов, либо не правильно ищу.

1. пропадает фокус у поля input с номером карты. из-за этого
   приходится каждый раз менять раскладку с текстового ввода на
   цифровой
2. на Sony ZR, Android 5.1.1. при вводе номера карты цифры
   переставляются местами

Можете хотя бы подсказать в каком направлении искать?

Comment: А что за цифры после вопроса?

Comment: для определения количества символов, их может быть и 16, и 19

Comment: Тогда у вас все правильно

Comment: в этой части да, правильно. но если редактировать введенный номер, цифры затираются...

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, уже в который раз от вас вопрос БЕЗ кода демонстрирующего проблему. Пожалуйста, приложите рабочий пример. Было бы просто чудесно, если бы вы еще приложили пример неверной работы. Например, ввожу в поле то-то, ожидаю увидеть то-то, а получается то-то.

Comment: не получается привести работающий/не работающий код. если вас не затруднит, покажите пожалуйста как тут http://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/vkfarha6/ подключить все плагины?

Comment: уточнила вопрос

Comment: спасибо, теперь стало понятнее, поставил плюс

Comment: спасибо, надо будет это отметить) я смотрю новичков тут не любят. меня уже почти забанили) я конечно понимаю, что это очень хороший профессиональный сервис. но как быть новичку, который иногда из-за не знания/не понимая не может задать вопрос, который всем понравится...

Comment: Посмотрите вот эту статью, в ней говорится, что считается хорошим вопросом: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2487/ К новичкам относятся хорошо, а вот к вопросам без четкого описания проблемы - плохо.

Comment: отредактировала вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы плагин заработал на jsfiddle, нужно подключить его с другого адреса: http://cdn.rawgit.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min.js

Подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github

В [примере](http://jsfiddle.net/vkfarha6/8/) описанной ошибки не заметил. Возможно, проблема в версии jQuery. Попробуйте обновиться до 2.2.0

Ваш код работает, как ожидается:

```
$("#acctNumber").mask("999999");
$("#sumCheck").mask("99999");
$("#cardNumber").mask("9999 9999 9999 9999?999");
$("#cardCode").mask("999");
```

Comment: спасибо, что подключили этот плагин! (а то прям беда какая-то). как раз в вашем работающем примере, ошибка хорошо воспроизводится. попробуйте отредактировать номер с середины например.

Comment: Цифры заменяют уже введеные. Ничего не "сдвигается". Общая длинна сохраняется при редактировании. В общем, не вижу ошибки.

Comment: @Microfed, вкратце, как я понял, нужно поведение, аналогичное поведению при нажатии на клавишу `insert` на клавиатуре. Сейчас если ввели 14 цифр из 16, а потом начали редактировать в середине, введенные цифры сдвигают остальные (всего цифр становится 16), а надо, чтобы оставалось 14 цифр и заменялись те цифры, возле которых стоит курсор

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно ограничение последние цифры должны быть три или четыре, то код такой

```
$("#cardNumber").mask("9999 9999 9999 999?9");
```

Comment: этот код не решает мою проблему